# Get Activity (this) inside setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm new in java and android development and I have one issue, let me explain.
I have custom interface and custom class which use this as a listener.

In my HomeActivity I call method on my custom class and the class respond via listeners (interface), this is short version:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements WebClientResponseListener {
    private User user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //....
        // I call my class and add this as a listener:
        MyWebServiceClient mws = new MyWebServiceClient(getApplicationContext());
        mws.getProducts(this.user.getToken(), this)
    }
    //....
    @Override
    public void onDataDownloadSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Log.d("DATA", "SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

When I run it like that everything works fine. The onDataDownloadSuccess method is called and I can see log output.

The issue appears when I try to run it from OnClickListener:

```
private void sendRequest() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.request_info_title));
    builder.setItems(items, this);
    //.....
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Later in the same activity I have:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
    MyWebServiceClient mws = new MyWebServiceClient(getApplicationContext());
     mws.getProducts(user.getToken(), this)
}
```

In this situation my listener onDataDownloadSuccess method is not called.
I can see in in the console:

> unregisterIRListener() is called

and

> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1613K, 35% free 13400K/20408K, paused 18ms, total
>   18ms

I was looking for the solution on line and I've already tried some stuff for example:

```
//in OnClick
mws.getProducts(user.getToken(), HomeActivity.this);
```

I created private variable HomeActivity and in onCreate I call

```
homeActivity = this;
```

and later in onClick I was trying to pass homeActivity instead of this
but with no luck. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: who is responsible to call onDataDownloadSuccess ?

Comment: @blackbelt MyWebServiceClient when finished download the data call onDataDownloadSuccess.

Comment: is the onClick declared inside an inner temporary class?

Comment: @blackbelt no it's directly in HomeActivity class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you need `context` and not `activity`, variable needs to be:

```
Context homeActivity;
```

or

```
Context context;
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
context=this;
```

use that `context` or `homeActivity` in your activity  or `HomeActivity.this`

Inside the click listener, "`this`" is a reference for the click listener.

Comment: I tried like that and it doesn't work either with context or HomeActivity.this

Comment: @Greg try passing the value instead of this.user.getToken()  . See what happens. Are you sure it reaches inside the click listener?

Comment: If I add context to getProducts method, it doesn't allow me, because of: getProducts(java....WebClientResponseListener) in com....ToolstreamWebServiceClient cannot be applied to (java...,android.content.Context). I tried to cast it to (HomeActivity)context in getProducts but it doesn't work, onDataDownloadSuccess is not called.

Comment: pls post your activity code in the question, the error you are getting says it wants a context and not a listener reference

Comment: Sorry there was mistake in my question I call this.user... just in onCreate method, later in onClick I refer to user as user...

Comment: and user.getToken has the correct value? the context part doesn't seem to be anything else, did you debug and check the flow..on what happens from onClick

Comment: It works if I pass value instead of user.getToken(). So the issue was with my user instance, listener works fine. Can you explain why it's like that? why it stop calling the onDataSuccess method? and How I should refer to private User user; variable in onClick method?

Comment: your user value is probably null, if not initialized or assigned anywhere else

Answer (score 13):

always try to use **YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this** because when you use only **"this"**, it point to the current `context` . let say you are in `OnClickListener` , it is an anonymous class so, when you use **this** inside this. it will point to the `button` not to the `activity`. Therefore, you need to point towards activity by using **activityname.this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of `Context` and initialize it to `this` outside the listener, and then just call it where you need it

Answer (score 0):

The above solution should work perfectly fine but still adding some flavors in it. Thought it will be helpful for someone to understand better.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context sampleActivityContext; 
private Button continueButton;
// All your class level variables/fields declared in this section

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sampleActivityContext = this; // Assigning the current activity(i.e.,) SampleActivity context
    .......
    continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continueButton); // Map the UI element from the XML to the corresponding java element
    .......  
   // Setting the onclick listener for the button 
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
 @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
 // When you need the context of the activity use sampleActivityContext 
 // instead of this keyword as this will refer the current view/button within the section 
// or you can prefer SampleActivity.this as well 

} 
}
```